# XSLT copy child nodes in parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to copy child elements into the parent element.

input

```
<csv>
<row>
    <stuff>a</stuff>
    <more>1</more>
    <evenmore>123</evenmore>
    <row>
        <other>1345</other>
        <stuff>dga</stuff>
    </row>
</row>
<row>
    <stuff>b</stuff>
    <more>2</more>
    <evenmore>456</evenmore>
    <row>
        <other>4576</other>
        <stuff>jzj</stuff>
    </row>
</row>
</csv>
```

desired output

```
<csv>
<row>
    <stuff>a</stuff>
    <more>1</more>
    <evenmore>123</evenmore>
    <other>1345</other>
    <stuff>dga</stuff>
</row>
<row>
    <stuff>b</stuff>
    <more>2</more>
    <evenmore>456</evenmore>
    <other>4576</other>
    <stuff>jzj</stuff>
</row>
</csv>
```

What I tried (the output stays the same like the input):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::row/row/other | child::row/row/stuff"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am sure to miss something very simple here. It should not be a problem, that the child element has the same name as the parent element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need your second template to only match the child `row`, and not the parent one. Then you can select its children, but just not copy it itself

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/row">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works just fine, thanks a lot! But I can't get my head around it. Where do you adress the first row element?

Comment: The identity template handles that. In a sense, the parent row is not changing, so you copy that as-is. You transformation is to "remove the child row, but retain its children"